What does the identity $(\mathbf{v} \cdots \mathbf{v}') \mathbf{1}= \mathbf{v}^{\mathsf{T}} \mathbf{v}'$ mean?
What does the identity
$$
(\mathbf{v} \cdots \mathbf{v}') \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{v}^{\mathsf{T}} \mathbf{v}'
$$
mean where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector/matrix? I understand that $\mathbf{x}^\mathsf{T}$ denotes a transposed vector and that $\mathbf{x}'$ is the complex conjugate, however that doesn't work in matrix multiplication (to the best of my knowledge). I'm especially curious about the $\mathbf{1}$ on the left hand side of the equation
This comes from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.11165 in appendix A.1
Sorry for any mistakes, this is my first question. Thanks for the help!

The $\mathbf 1$ is a vector of $1$s. But this “identity” makes no sense to me.

The "identity" doesn't even seem to match the thing it's supposed to explain. I suggest contacting the authors for an explanation. Perhaps there is a typo that they can fix.

I'd speculate the intent is that $\cdots$ should be $\circ$ for entry-wise multiplication. This is then nearly sensible: the entrywise product $\mathbf{v}\circ \mathbf{v}'$ would have $k$th element $v_k v_k'$, so taking the dot product with the ones vector would sum up these to get the dot product $\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{v}'$. However, in that case it seems like the identity should be $(\mathbf{v}\circ \mathbf{v}')^\top \mathbf{1}=\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{v}'$ which doesn't match the source usage. (Also, $\mathbf{v}'$ is just notating "another vector" not an operation on $\mathbf{v}$.)
